# VS2010 builds an exe but cant debug it complaining it cant find it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am currently working on a project VS2010 C++ in which VS2010 successfully builds a project at the path showing in the output

```
1>  Level2Socket.vcxproj -> C:\Project\LSock.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I click on the project and select Debug >> Start new instance Visual Studio states

```
Unable to start program the system cannot find the  C:\Project\LSock.exe file specified.
```

And I double checked the presence of the file it does exist there. Any suggestions on why I am getting this ?

Comment: project -> properties -> debugging , setup Working directory to your Project directory, i guess you changed default output directory in General options.

Comment: @user928204 The console output suggests otherwise.

Comment: I realize that VS said build successful however does the exe C:\Project\LSock.exe actually exist?

Comment: yes it does. @user928204 solution worked. Could you post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

project -> properties -> debugging , setup Working directory to your Project directory.